# How to return a matrix in a libre office calc basic function?

Tags: function, matrix, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

To enter a function that returns a matrix, I know I have to select all the cells for the returning variant and press `CTRL SHIFT ENTER`. The function can be defined as this minimal example:

```
Function test() as Variant
    dim res(1)
    res(0) = "test 0"
    res(1) = "test 1"
    test = res
end function
```

Then in the cell itself: `{=test()}`.

But it does not work. I have also tested `test() = res()`.

Result is `test 0` in both cells.

Comment: Stab in the dark: are the cells you selected aligned in a row or in a column? e.g. A1:B1 or A1:A2?

Comment: In a column like A1:A2

Comment: What's the result if you use A1:B1? Or if you use `TRANSPOSE` and A1:A2?

Comment: it works. How can I use A1:A2 ?

Comment: Another stab: `TRANSPOSE`.

Comment: `test = transpose(res)` changes nothing. What's the right way?

Comment: In A1: `=TRANSPOSE(test())`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255473/discussion-between-lalebarde-and-bigben).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test either of these at the moment, but either `TRANSPOSE` when calling from the worksheet cell:

```
=TRANSPOSE(test())
```

or try using a 2D array:

```
Function test() as Variant
    dim res(0 to 1, 0 to 0)
    res(0, 0) = "test 0"
    res(1, 0) = "test 1"
    test = res
end function
```